# How construct a one-to-many relationship form in Play with Scala and Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.2

Based on [@JacobusR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14707468/176510) how can I program a form in the controller that allows me to send it to the view as a Form type with all one-side table columns mapping and many-side table seq-mapping?

Something like this:

**In the Controller**

```
private val DirectorateAndItsServiceAreas: Form[???] = Form(
mapping(
  "dirCode" -> nonEmptyText,
  "name" -> text,
  "serviceAreaRow" -> seq( /* don't have and don't want serviceAreasRow in Directorate table */
    mapping(
      "areaCode" -> nonEmptyText,
      "dirCode" -> nonEmptyText,
      "name" -> text
    )(ServiceArea.apply)(ServiceArea.unapply)
  )
)(Directorate.apply)(Directorate.unapply)
```

)

**In the View**

```
@(DirectorateAndItsServiceAreasForm: Form[Directorate/ServiceArea],...
```

Comment: Well have you tried this yet and why is this not working?